# PHP Array multilevel to echo

Tags: php, arrays

I have a problem again with arrays :(
I have this:

```
Array
(
  [results] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [backdrop_path] => htttp://link.com/img.jpg
                [id] => 23951
                [title] => 1
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [backdrop_path] => htttp://link.com/img.jpg
                [id] => 23952
                [title] => 2
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [backdrop_path] => htttp://link.com/img.jpg
                [id] => 23953
                [title] => 3
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [backdrop_path] => htttp://link.com/img.jpg
                [id] => 23954
                [title] => 4
            )
    )
```

)

How can I convert it to this:

title: 1

title: 2

title: 3

title: 4

Thank you so much!

Comment: `foreach ($mysterious_unnamed_array['results'] as $result) echo '<li>title: '.$result['title'].'</li>';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use foreach

```
echo '<ul>';
foreach ($array['results'] as $element) {
    echo "<li>title: {$element['title']}</li>";
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!empty($array['results'])){
   echo '<ul>';
   foreach ($array['results'] as $a){
      echo "<li>title: {$a['title']}</li>";
   }
   echo '</ul>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use [array_map()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) instead of `foreach()` or `for` loop. Example:

```
echo '<ul>';
array_map(function($v){echo '<li>Title: '.$v['title'].'</li>';}, $str['results']);
echo '</ul>';
```